# Is there a way to relate custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'd like to be able to choose an object from another custom post type I've created when adding a second type.  Similar to the way you can choose an author for a post.

So when creating a post of type B there would be a dropdown of all the post As that the current author has created.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestions or direction.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "object". Do you mean custom field data, a category/tag, a taxonomy?

Comment: Sorry, probably the wrong term.  I meant creating an item of that type.  So for example if post type A were Teams and type B were players.  When creating a player I could select which team they are on.

Comment: Creating a taxonomy would work if the team name were all I were concerned with, but there are more fields for a team than just the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably this plugin:

Posts 2 Posts http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.  Thanks goldenapples

Comment: For anyone else having this issue, Posts 2 Posts is a fantastic plugin. Gave me all the tools I needed.